# Can not stop submit event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this to validate my form but I can stop the submit event on my page. It still sends data and submit that. Why? How can I stop it?

```js
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
        if ($('#input-name').val() === '' && $('#input-phone-number').val() === '' && $('#input-address').val() === '' && $('#input-email').val() === '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.noti-container').css({
                'opacity': '1',
                'z-index': '9999',
                'top': '20px',
                'background': '#FFCCCC'
            });
            $('.icon-container').html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');
            $('.notif').text('Please fill all field!');
            $('.notif').css({'color': 'black'});
            $('.icon-container').css({
                'background': '#F2F5A9'
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.noti-container').css({
                    'opacity': '0',
                    'z-index': '-1',
                    'top': '0',
                })
            }, 1500);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: put this - `e.preventDefault();` outside of `if` condition

Comment: I think your problem is with the validation. The way you've written the conditions, it will only be invalid if ALL of the fields are empty (since you're using `&&`). I assume you want it to be invalid if any of the fields are empty (use `||` instead).

Comment: @Lennholm That's right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` seems to be present in the if block. If the *if condition* resolves to false, the form will be submitted. You need to move `e.preventDefault();` code before if block to prevent submission on all cases.

Example:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Remaining Code
}
```

Comment: But when I don't fill one of these input tags. The submit still going to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Have added some changes, Try this

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert('submit event stop');


    if ($('#input-name').val() === '' && $('#input-phone-number').val() === '' && $('#input-address').val() === '' && $('#input-email').val() === '') {

        $('.noti-container').css({
            'opacity': '1',
            'z-index': '9999',
            'top': '20px',
            'background': '#FFCCCC'
        });
        $('.icon-container').html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');
        $('.notif').text('Please fill all field!');
        $('.notif').css({'color': 'black'});
        $('.icon-container').css({
            'background': '#F2F5A9'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.noti-container').css({
                'opacity': '0',
                'z-index': '-1',
                'top': '0',
            })
        }, 1500);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```